# Is it a smooth simple arc

Tags: vector-analysis

A curve C is a smooth simple arc if it has a 1-1 smooth ($C^1$ and $f'(t)\neq 0 $) parametrization of the form $f: [a,b]\to R^n$

Let C be a curve parametrized by f(t)=(t^3,t^5) on [-1,1].
My book claims C is smooth simple because of the paramterization $(t,t^{5/3})$. But I thought this isn't smooth because at 0, the derivative is also 0. What am I missing?

Comment: Let's use another example.  Consider the line $f(t) = (t,t)$.  This is a smooth curve (a line).  However, I could just as easily use the parameterization $f(t) = (t^3,t^3)$, which in fact does have a vanishing derivative at $0$.  Would you call the straight line not smooth?  You just need one parameterization that does not have vanishing derivative.

Comment: got it, thanks.